# How to make simple modal login work with non-modal wordpress login screens

Tags: wordpress, authentication, simplemodal

The SimpleModal Login plugin for wordpress seems to have pretty nice functionality for creating  login, registration, and forgot_password modals that can be made to pop up in the foreground using the link: `<a href="/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" class="login_style simplemodal-login">Login</a>` but a problem occurs when accessing a non-modal WP login screen ("www.site.com/wp-login.php" or "/wp-admin") where the links from that WP login screen start to be read by the modal .js file before the simplemodal html has fully been established (which it hasn't on a non-modal wp-login page).

So, how can you make those links work for those non-modal access points? See my own solution below...

Answer (score 0):

Towards the top of the .js file of the theme you are using (ex: .../plugins/simplemodal-login/js/default.js), right inside the init:function{ bracket, place the following:

```
var this_url = window.location.href;
var is_nonmodal_login = this_url.search(/wp-login|wp-admin/);
if (is_nonmodal_login >= 0){
    return;
}
```

This is a somewhat simple solution that simply stops the script from continuing any further and allows for the actual default href values of the non-modal screens to be loaded into the browser, and the user redirected appropriately, without the script operating on the url and continuing to try to .show a modal dialog.

Note however that there may be other ways to access the wp-login for your site that should be addressed too...